# Can't figure out why this MySQL query is slow

Tags: mysql

I have one particular MySQL query which is slow, and I can't figure out why.

```
SELECT 
    s.title, 
    p.minPrice, 
    s.booking, r.url 
FROM shows s 
INNER JOIN showResources r 
    ON r.showID = s.id 
INNER JOIN performances p 
    ON p.showID = s.id  
WHERE s.lastDate >= CURDATE() 
    AND r.type = 'rectangle-poster' 
    AND p.minPrice > 0 
GROUP BY s.id 
ORDER BY p.minPrice ASC 
LIMIT 30
```

The EXPLAIN for this query is as follows:

```
    select_type table type  possible_keys    key       key_len ref          rows extra
1   SIMPLE      s     range PRIMARY,lastDate lastDate  4       NULL         291  Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      r     ref   showID,type      showID    5       thistle.s.id 1    Using where
1   SIMPLE      p     ref   showID,minPrice  showID    5       thistle.s.id 1    Using where
```

Other, seemingly far more complex queries on the same server are blisteringly fast - but this one typically takes about 4 seconds to run, and I just can't figure out why. I've even gone as far as deleting the tables and recreating them just in case it was some weird corruption, but no luck. Can a MySQL expert tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you make an SQL fiddle with example data please

Comment: `Using filesort` - your sort isn't index based.

Comment: Ok, understood - by why not? lastDate has an index - why wouldn't it be using it?

Comment: Your query looks possibly invalid because you are grouping by `s.id` but selecting `r.url`.

Comment: Tim - not sure I understand. I'm grouping by the shows table because there may be multiple showResources and/or performances, but I only need one to be returned. Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: If only it was illegal to use a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions. Either way, it's definitely nonsensical, so instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    s.id AS id,
    s.title, 
    p.minPrice AS min_price, 
    s.booking,
    r.url 
FROM shows s 
INNER JOIN showResources r 
    ON r.showID = s.id AND s.lastDate >= CURDATE() AND r.type = 'rectangle-poster'
INNER JOIN performances p 
    ON p.showID = s.id AND p.minPrice > 0  
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY min_price ASC 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Thanks, but still slow and the EXPLAIN is the same.

Comment: shows has approx 28K, performances ~ 380K and showResources ~ 5K

Comment: I think you've got too many rows to perform the `join` operation. Thus it requires large amounts of memory, and runs slowly. So I would suggest you  reduce the row count for `join` as many as possible.